# Difference between the types of accessing pointer values in golang

Tags: go, pointers, struct, reference

Consider the below example

```
type Employee struct {
    Firstname string
    // other fields
}

func (e *Employee) SetName(name string) {
   e.Firstname = name // type 1
   (*e).firstName = name // type 2
}
```

What is the difference between type 1 and type 2 ways of accessing properties here? When should we use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type 1 is a shorthand for type 2.  Use the shorthand notation.

Here's the [quote from the specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors):

> if the type of x is a defined pointer type and (*x).f is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), x.f is shorthand for (*x).f.